# GSP include - with parameters -within g:each?

Tags: grails, groovy, taglib, gsp

I have some common structure that I'd like to use, and I need to nest it within a `<g:each />`. The semantic solution seems to be to create a taglib, but I'd rather write GSP code to construct the structure, as it's easier to read/maintain.

Essentially, I need this:

```
<g:each ...>
  //Somehow include a GSP that takes parameter "datastructure1"
  //Again with "datastructure2"
</g:each>
```

A GSP include takes params, but it's not nestable in a `<g:each />`. What am I looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<g:include>` works as you need it to. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a taglib, then in the taglib function: render a template. There's an example [here](http://jan-so.blogspot.com/2009/09/getting-data-into-grails-tags-and.html).